# should my core in clean arch be library independent?

Tags: clean-architecture

I´m Implementing "The Clean Architecture" in my Project.

I´m Using scala as my langauge.

Now I´m dealing with following question:

Should my "Core" ( Use Cases / Entities ) be library Independent, so just plain ( In my case Scala ) code or would you say, that I could, if I wantet use librarys for example the effect library "ZIO"?

Or would It depend on the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clean Architecture the "core" should be as independent from external libraries as possible.

Some libraries cannot be avoided (you want to use collections and other types from the "base libraries" of your development platform) but every library you use in the "core" you effectively "marry" which means it will be super hard or even impossible to get rid of it or replace it later on in the lifetime of your project.

So it has to be a careful and conscious decision to use a library in the "core" of your application.